# Executing PHP function on click of a link

Tags: php

I want to trigger a PHP function on click of a link or button. How can I do it? I have used javascript onclick functionality but is there any way to do so ?

Comment: You can use `Ajax` posts to trigger PHP with Javascript.

Comment: Does the function have to be executed without a page refresh?

Comment: You have to be describe your problem in your question , not just type what you want to do and just post it. Also post the code you have attempted to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Better go for jquery, ajax for sending data in json format.! Like

**code.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){

        var status = $('form')[0].checkValidity();
        if(status){
            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "code.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: "JSON",   

                success: function(json){
                    if(json.error){
                        alert(json.error_msg);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }else{
                        alert("Data stored successfully!");
                    }
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

**code.php**

```
<?php
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','***');
    define('PASS','***');
    define('DB','***');

    $response = array();

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

    if(!mysqli_connect_errno()){

        $error_flag = false;
        /*foreach($_POST as $value){
            if(empty($value)){
                $error_flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }*/

        if(!$error_flag){

            //receiving post parameters
             $sdn =$_POST['sdn'];




                                    // create a new user profile
                                    $sql = "INSERT INTO safety(sdn, created_at) VALUES ('$sdn',NOW())";
                                    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                                        $response["error"] = false;
                                        echo json_encode($response);

                                    }else{
                                        $response["error"] = true;
                                        $response["error_msg"] = "INSERT operation failed";
                                        echo json_encode($response);
                                    }

        }else{
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Few fields are missing";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

    }else{
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Database connection failed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

And lastly use jquery link inside 

**code.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "code.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="form" name ="form" method = "POST" action="Next_page.html" class="wizard-big" autocomplete = "off">

<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
<input type="text" placeholder="sdn" class="form-control"  id="sdn" name="sdn">
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
<input style="width:100%" type="submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Save and continue"  class="btn btn-success">
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTTP/1.1 404 `jquery_source.js` Not Found!

Comment: oops..! Thanks for that, think i missed to mention the actual link! ill update it

Comment: or if you really want it simple with just as one click, well then just write php functionality in a file and give the href link of <a> in your front end file to that php file and in php file by using "header()" function, redirect it to page you want or use js window function as an alternative way to redirect to avoid some problems in header();.!